# WiFi not chosing a strongest signal

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, network-manager

My computer does not connect to the strongest signal router. You can check the output when i run `nmcli dev wifi` (keep in mind that router in use is marked with `*` in the left column):

```
IN-USE  SSID                    MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY                                                                                             
        Gerald von Riva 2,4GHz  Infra  11    540 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆_  WPA2                                                                                   
        WHB                     Infra  9     270 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  WPA2                                                                                                                       
        Gerald von Riva 5GHz    Infra  108   540 Mbit/s  55      ▂▄__  WPA2                                                                                                              
        WHB                     Infra  9     270 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA2
        EasyBox-901479          Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2
        WHB                     Infra  9     270 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA2
        o2-WLAN94               Infra  4     130 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄__  WPA2
*       WHB                     Infra  40    405 Mbit/s  48      ▂▄__  WPA2
        FRITZ!Box 7412          Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  45      ▂▄__  WPA2
        WHB                     Infra  8     270 Mbit/s  45      ▂▄__  WPA2
```

All routers in network I have access to, are marked with SSID: `WHB`. But for some reason my computer connects to the `WHB CHAN 40`, but `WHB CHAN 9` has much better signal. How to force computer to connect to strongest signal WiFi?

Comment: Just an observation: your router has chosen the WHB SSID with the highest rate.

Comment: @PonJar Thanks for observation. I think it was rather accidentally. Because I have checked some saved info from before and there, I was connected to `WHB` SSID  which had the same rate as the strongest `WHB` at that moment.

Comment: Hi @vaso, did you finally find the reason for this issue? I'm experiencing the same problem in my Ubuntu 22.04. Thanks.